# Why do we call doesNotRecognizeSelector: method?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsobject

I am working with socket programming.I just wanted to clear a doubt related with a code i downloaded from -[mobileorchard.com - Chatty](http://www.mobileorchard.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/chatty.zip). While R&D , I saw a function call in **ChatRoomViewController.m** file

```
 [chatRoom broadcastChatMessage:input.text fromUser:[AppConfig getInstance].name];
```

when I saw in **Room.m**  file, for the implementation of above call; it was

```
- (void)broadcastChatMessage:(NSString*)message fromUser:(NSString*)name
{
    // Crude way to emulate an "abstract" class
    [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd];
}
```

i googled for "doesNotRecognizeSelector:" , according to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/doesNotRecognizeSelector:) its for error handling, stating "The runtime system invokes this method whenever an object receives an aSelector message it can’t respond to or forward." my question is why does the developer call the **broadcastChatMessage:fromUser:** function if its none of use there and to handle which method's "selector not found" exception ?

According to [Stackovrflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1034373/1030951), its used to create abstract class , according to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2854522/1030951), its to avoid "Incomplete implementation" warning.

I am still not getting why that method is used in that [Chatty Code](http://www.mobileorchard.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/chatty.zip), Kindly help me to understand the reason why that method is used.

Comment: It looks as though the original developer of the application was attempting to emulate the features of a C++ abstract base class, in that instances of it are invalid.  It's simply a more extreme form of making methods do nothing or return a placeholder value (usually 0 or NULL).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the method that exists on every `NSObject` derived object that triggers the path to an exception when a method isn't recognized in a runtime call. For example, if you try to send a message to an `NSString` called `-foo`, it'll end up there since that's not a valid method on `NSString`.

In this case, the Chatty class `Room` is a base class that is never used directly. `LocalRoom` and `RemoteRoom` derive from it, and both of those classes provide an overriding implementation of `-broadcastChatMessage:fromUser`. Nobody ever calls that base class version, but for "completeness" the programmer has guaranteed that a subclasser must override this by implementing the method, but then turning around and calling this to trigger an exception.

Thing is, this isn't specifically idiomatic Objective-C. An "abstract" class is a concept from C++ and other languages; it's base class that exists only as a "pattern" from which to subclass. (In ObjC, this is often done by creating a formal `@protocol` when there isn't meaningful state, as there (mostly) isn't here).

Note that the call to `-doesNotRecognizeSelector:` is arbitrary. It's not necessary to avoid compiler warnings here (since the method is in fact implemented) and the original writer could have easily just thrown an exception directly, or done nothing instead.

Comment: I think the official apple doc do this first see the doc of  `-doesNotRecognizeSelector: ` API  saying - " However, they can be used in program code to prevent a method from being inherited."

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that you already answered your own question.  There is no method to make abstract classes in Objective-C, so the closest thing to do it to have the methods that you need to override throw exceptions.  If you override this method in a subclass, then `doesNotRecognizeSelector:` will no longer be called.  Basically it is a way to get a developer to promise to implement this method in their subclass.

Also, as you mentioned, if you don't put this in then the compiler will issue a warning because no implementation exists for a method defined in the header.  This will perform the same behavior as not implementing it, but the compiler will realize that you are doing it on purpose.